# How to obtain BEFORE and AFTER state of my object's related attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have the following relationship:

```
Document has_and_belongs_to_many Users
User has_and_belongs_to_many Documents
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to perform the following:
Let's say a document has 3 users which belong to it. If after an update they become for ex. 4, I would like to send an email
message (document_updated) to the first 3 and a different email message (document_assigned) to the 4th.

**So I have to know the users belonging to my Document BEFORE and AFTER the Document update occurs.**

My approach so far has been to create an Observer like this:

```
class DocumentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_update(document)
    # this works because of ActiveModel::Dirty
    # @old_subject=document.subject_was    #subject is a Document attribute (string)

    # this is not working - I get an 'undefined method' error 
    @old_users=document.users_was   

    @new_users=document.users.all.dup

    # perform calculations to find out who the new users are and send emails....
  end
end
```

I knew that my chances of @old_users taking a valid value were slim because I guess it is populated dynamically by rails via the has_and_belongs_to_many relation.

So my question is:

How do I get all my related users before an update occurs?

*(some other things I've tried so far:)*

A. Obtaining document.users.all inside DocumentController::edit. This returns a valid array, however I do not know how to pass this array to
DocumentObserver.after_update in order to perform the calculations (just setting an instance variable inside DocumentController is of course not working)

B. Trying to save document.users inside DocumentObserver::before_update. This is not working either. I still get the new user values

Thanks in advance

George

Ruby 1.9.2p320

Rails 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `before_add` callback

```
class Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :before_add => :do_stuff

  def  do_stuff(user)
  end
end
```

When you add a user to a document that callback will be called and at that point `self.users` will still it yet contain the user you are adding.

If you need something more complicated it might be simpler to have a `set_users` method on document

```
def set_users(new_user_set)
  existing = users
  new_users = users - new_user_set
  # send your emails
  self.users = new_user_set
end
```

Comment: Thanks. However this per-user granularity approach solves part of the problem. 

I can effectively send all the "document_assigned" emails this way (inside do_stuff), but if two users are added at the same time 
(for ex. u4 and u5) then:

1. document_assigned email of u4 will have no way of informing him that u5 is also assigned
2. I will still be unable to find the initial users that they (and only they) receive the "document_updated" email.
(Sending "document_updated" inside do_stuff will cause multiple emails to be sent, sending it inside Observer will also include the newly added users)

Comment: There might not be something completely built in to do this - I've given one alternative approach